# "When" as a conjunction

Tags: conjunctions, conditional-constructions

As we speak using a conjunction like:

> - "When joy will come, then we will go to market."
> - "We will go to market when joy comes."

Which of these sentences are correct in speaking English?

Comment: Both answers are correct, however the first sentence would need to be changed to `"When joy comes, we will go to market"`

Comment: Is joy a person? If so, you need to capitalize the j. Also, what is the source of these sentences?

Comment: The second one is correct, but if joy is someone's name, it needs a capital letter thus: "Joy". Incidentally, "when" is not a conjunction; it is a preposition.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/question-words/when

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence is not grammatical, whereas the second is Ok.

When you talk about the future with the conjunction when,  you use the present simple or the present perfect in the when-clause, not the future with shall or will.

When Joy comes, we will go to the market.